# 404 (Not Found) on my icon.svg - Ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, svg, icons

I have an icon in my folder app > assets > medias > logo-footer.svg
In my code it looks like this :

```
<img loading="lazy" class="footer__logo" src="app/assets/medias/logo-footer.svg" alt="Logo">
```

In my application I have an error in my console: GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/icons.svg 404 (Not Found).

How can I set the right path to this icon.svg ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`asset_path`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) helper to generate the path to the image instead of hardcoding it:

```
<img loading="lazy" class="footer__logo" src="
<%=asset_path("logo-footer.svg")%>" alt="Logo">
```

You can also use [`image_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper:

```
<%= image_tag(logo-footer.svg, alt:"Logo", class: "footer__logo", loading: "lazy" %>
```

Read more in the [Asset Path Guideline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Thx for your answer, I tried the first solution and I now . have the following error undefined local variable or method `logo' for #<#<Class:0x00007f983b6a0358>:0x00007f983b6aaa88>

Comment: I also tried the second one it works like this : <%= image_tag("logo-footer.svg", alt:"Logo", class: "footer__logo", loading: "lazy" ) %>
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Also, do you have any idea how to write svg in css file ? I have something like : background-image: url("../../icons/hourglass.svg"); but doesn't work :(

Comment: Please add another question, add code examples, you'll reach a wider audience